Smooth approximation of the floor function
Question
I am looking for a sequence of $C^\infty$ real functions $f_k(x)$ such that:
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}:\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_k(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$$
If the $C^\infty$ condition holds only for sufficiently large values of $k$, that is good enough.

Failed attempt #1
Defining a weighted sigmoid function: $$s_k\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}$$
Now,
$$f_k(x)=x+\left(2s_k\left(\sin\left(\pi x\right)\right)-1\right)\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\cos\left(\pi x\right)\right)}{\pi}-0.5$$
Desmos graph

However, the function fails on two counts:

It is not $C^\infty$ smooth, merely $C^1$
The limit of the function as $k\rightarrow \infty$ at integer values of $x$ is not $x$, but instead $x-0.5$


Failed attempt #2
Defining:
$$s_k\left(x\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x^{k}}{2}\right)$$
$$g\left(x\right)=\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\left(\pi\left(x-0.5\right)\right)\right)}{\pi}+0.5$$
$$f_k(x)=x-g\left(x\right)+s_k\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$$
Desmos graph

This function is also just $C^1$ smooth.

It is relatively easy to construct a sequence of smooth functions that converge to $\lfloor x \rfloor$ except on integers.

For $k\geq 2$ define $$f_k(x)=\begin{align}\begin{cases}0, &x\in [0,1-1/k]\\
\dfrac{e^\frac{-1}{x-(1-1/k)}}{e^\frac{-1}{x-(1-1/k)}+e^\frac{-1}{(1-1/2k)-x}},&x\in (1-1/k,1-1/2k)\\\\1,&x\in [1-1/2k,1]\end{cases}\end{align}$$
This is a classical smooth transition function.
One can easily check that $f_k(x)\to \begin{cases}0,\quad x\in [0,1)\\1,\quad x=1\end{cases}=\lfloor x\rfloor$.
This functions can be extended to smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$ in the natural way: considering these kinds of smooth transition functions when approaching every integer.
We have thus constructed a sequence of smooth functions that converge to $\lfloor x \rfloor$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. That a function with a closed support could be $C^\infty$ smooth was counterintuitive for me, but the derivative of $f_k(x)$ proves me wrong. Thanks again.

Any particular reason for choosing $k\geq2$ though? For example, what would be the problem with $k=1.5$?

@SohamSaha: $k$ is the index on a sequence of functions, so we would normally expect an integer there, that's all.

@BrianTung Understood. I was considering $k$ to be a real-valued parameter instead. Thanks!
